# C++ Continue Reading File After eof()?

Tags: c++, file-io, eof

I am building a program which reads text files, containing a list of numbers. These lists contain a series of sorted numbers, each which may contain a varying amount of values. For example, file 1 may have a list of 2 numbers and file 2 may have a list of 20.

The point of the program  is to read each of these text files (which contain numbers in ascending order) line by line, then put them into a new text file in ascending order. However, if one list is really short, then I will get an `eof()` error, causing the file reader to go into the fail state, which won't allow it to read the remaining values in the longer text file.

Here is my code which iterates over the two text files:

```
int main() {
int numbers1 = 0, numbers2 = 0, fillCounter = 0, iteration = 0;
char grabNext = 'b';
ifstream file1, file2, fileFiller;
ofstream fout;
file1.open("numbers1.txt");
file2.open("numbers2.txt");
fout.open("output.txt");

//Check and see if the opening operation was successful
if (file1.fail() || file2.fail()) {
    cout << "The progran could not open the related necessary files. Check and see if they exist!"
         << endl;

    exit(1);
}

do {
//In theory, whenever the file1 gives an eof, I should be able to iterate over the remaining lines of file2
    if (file1.eof()) {
        do {
            fout << numbers2 << endl;
        } while(!file2.eof());

        break;
    }

//In theory, whenever the file2 gives an eof, I should be able to iterate over the remaining lines of file1
    if (file2.eof()) {
        do {
            fout << numbers1 << endl;
            break;
        } while(!file1.eof());

        break;
    }

    if (grabNext == 'b') {
        file1 >> numbers1;
        file2 >> numbers2;
    } else if (grabNext == 'l') {
        file1 >> numbers1;
    } else if (grabNext == 'u') {
        file2 >> numbers2;
    }

    cout << numbers1 << " " << numbers2 << endl;

    if (numbers1 < numbers2) {
        fout << numbers1 << endl;
        grabNext = 'l';
    } else if (numbers1 > numbers2) {
        fout << numbers2 << endl;
        grabNext = 'u';
    }

    iteration++;
} while(true);
```

}

Here is example text file 1:

```
-1
3
5
7
9
```

Here is example text file 2:

```
2
4
10
12
16
```

My question is, after I reach `eof()` from one file, that I could continue to read the other until that one reaches `eof()`?

I have been looking everywhere with no luck.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The `eof` flag doesn't predict the future. It won't tell you if a future read will succeed but only why a past read failed. You need to use a read function that allows you to handle failure and then only stop when both files have failed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, David. I am relatively new to C++. Is there a chance that you could demo what you are talking about?

Comment: See [this page](http://mathbits.com/mathbits/compsci/files/end.htm) for an example of how to read data in a way that lets you handle failure and then process the data only if the read succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you also have infinite loops:

```
do {
        fout << numbers1 << endl;
        break;
    } while(!file1.eof());
```

Nothing is changing inside the loop to cause file1 to approach eof().

Comment: There's no loop there are all, due to the `break;`.

Comment: Whoops - the infinite loop is in the other case: 


    if (file1.eof()) {
        do {
            fout << numbers2 << endl;
        } while(!file2.eof());

        break;
    }